# How can I take an input 'n' to define a matrix of order n in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, input

```
    num_array = list()
    num = input("Enter how many elements you want:")
    print('Enter numbers in array: ')
    for i in range(int(num)):
        n=input("num :")
        num_array.append(int(n))
    print('ARRAY: ',num_array)
```

this one was there but it's not gonna give me matrix of order n

Comment: What did you get?  What did you expect?  Your question is incomplete.  I think the variable name should be more descriptive, like `alist`.  It isn't a `numpy` array.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want a matrix representation, you should go with a list of lists. You only input n numbers, but for a matrix you need n*n numbers. Do that with a second for loop like so:

```
# matrix is gonna be a list of lists 
num_array = list()

num = input("Enter how many elements you want:")
print('Enter numbers in array: ')

# first for iterates for rows
for i in range(int(num)):
    row = list()
    # second for iterates numbers in every row
    for j in range(int(num)):
        n = input("num :")
        row.append(int(n))
    num_array.append(row)

# output as matrix
for row in num_array:
    for number in row:
        print(number, end=" ")
    print()
```